# Do we want/can we have MathJax?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Coming from the physics SE, I'm quite accustomed to being able to write math-mode LaTeX in questions, answers, and comments. I think that would be useful here as well. I expect others would be mostly in favor of this, so I'm curious if anybody feels that this would be bad.

If we agree that we want it, then how do we go about getting it?

Comment: If it's anything like it was in the early days of physics, someone from the SE team will enable it if this question gets enough upvotes to indicate community support for the idea.

Comment: ...especially if enough questions show up that prove the necessity

Comment: I could have already used it, having put "delta t" in an answer.

Comment: I've been writing latex all over the place, hoping that it will render after they add MathJax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You go about getting it by posting a request on meta. (:

This has been enabled now, enjoy!

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: This is wonderful! Thanks for enabling it here.