# Why can't we use latex markup to put math in the questions on this site?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we want/can we have MathJax?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/do-we-want-can-we-have-mathjax)

On math.stackexchange, you can type, e.g.

$$\alpha \le \beta$$

and get mathematical output in your question/answer
(see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Given the mathematical nature of our discipline, why isn't this site set up the same?  How can we add latex-style markup to the site?

Comment: Someone on the dev team will need to enable it, if the community does indeed believe it'll be useful. (I suspect it will be) In the meantime I'm voting to migrate this to meta.